Not able to click button and prevent form submission
I'm having this problem if I click on submit button, it gives me this error
[org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported
But if i use event.preventDefault(); in js function, i'm not even able to click the button
This is my html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spring Boot WebSocket Chat Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chat.css" />
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <h2>Sorry! Your browser doesn't support Javascript</h2>
</noscript>

<form id="connectButton" name="connectButton">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="start-chatting-button" class="accent username-submit">Start Chatting</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="chat-page" class="hidden">
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-header">
            <h2>Spring WebSocket Chat</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="connecting">
            Connecting...
        </div>
        <ul id="messageArea">

        </ul>
        <form id="messageForm" name="messageForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group clearfix">
                    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type a message..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="primary">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

This is my js file
'use strict';

var chatgroupPage = document.querySelector('#chatgroup-page');
var chatPage = document.querySelector('#chat-page');
var chatGroupFindForm = document.querySelector('#chatGroupFindForm');
var messageForm = document.querySelector('#messageForm');
var messageInput = document.querySelector('#message');
var messageArea = document.querySelector('#messageArea');
var connectingElement = document.querySelector('.connecting');


var stompClient = null;
var username = null;

var colors = [
    '#2196F3', '#32c787', '#00BCD4', '#ff5652',
    '#ffc107', '#ff85af', '#FF9800', '#39bbb0'
];

function connect(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var username = 'Dhananjai';
    console.log("Inside connect function");
    if(username) {

        console.log("Inside connect function if condition");

        chatgroupPage.classList.add('hidden');
        chatPage.classList.remove('hidden');

//        var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
//        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

//        stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
    }

}

document.getElementById('start-chatting-button').addEventListener('click', connect, true);

Tried prevent event defaults, also used 'click' instead of 'submit', didn't work

Normally, you would use type="submit" on you submit button, and add the event submit on the form not on the button itself
<button type="submit" id="start-chatting-button" class="accent username-submit">Start Chatting</button>

and
messageForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // get your fields and send the appropriate request...
})

